# Slide between two Activites in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

So I in my Main Activity I have a screen which looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAxw3.png

So I want to slide between two different activites. Is there a way to do that

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can slide in an activity between two fragments but not in between two activities. Just use ViewPager2 to slide between fragments. Set both your activity names to the bottom navigation bar and integrate it with ViewPager2.

https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide-2

You can go through the official google documentation to implement ViewPager2 in your app.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce two activities into "SingleActivity-TwoFragments" pattern and use `ViewPager` to swipe between those `Fragments`.
Here is the android documentation on how to slide between `Fragments` using `ViewPager` :
https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide